# Regularization for classification problems without use of neural network (using R)

Tags: machine-learning, classification, random-forest

I am trying to use regularization methods for a classification problem, but without neural networks. I searched online and I found that the most famous algorithms are Ridge, Lasso, Elastic net but these are for regressions, and other methods for neural network. Are they any algorithms for my problem using a random forest (using R) ? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can do regularized logistic regression using the [`glmnet` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/index.html), e.g., `glmnet(..., family="binomial")`.

And of course the [`randomForest`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/index.html) package allows you to do classification, too.